# Multiple redirects google chrome iframe

Tags: html, google-chrome, redirect, iframe

I have a problem where when trying to load a webpage into an iframe it displays a blank page instead of the content.

I have found that it is when the page I am trying to show is redirecting multiple times, in this case 3.

I do not have access to the page I am trying to load so can not take out some of the redirects, it is on a seperate domain but does not have the x-frame-options sameorigin header so it is not that.

It works on firefox though.

Has anyone else run into a problem like this?